Furnace roof opening
I have been trying to find answers about a opening on the roof to the outside I have above my furnace in a closet. I live in a hot desert climate and I think the hot air coming in is effecting my air conditioner temp intake and effecting the air temperature in my house Which is 80 degrees in take and 90 in the house.So my question is it safe to have someone close the roof? Or does the furnace need the fresh air for the winter. It does have a pipe going from the furnace to the outside. Thank you

Gas furnace must have fresh air supply.
However since you are not using it in summer you can close the vent.
For safety reason, install a valve that opens when furnace is running.
You could use a zone damper valve that is controlled by 24 volt and the signal to start the furnace
If you do not already have it, install carbon monoxide detector for safety
